# Creating pandas series from two given pd.Series

Tags: python, pandas, series

I'm having a pandas issue.

So I have a pd.Series, `serie_1`, that looks like the following:

```
timestamp
2010-05-01      2
2010-06-01      1
2010-07-01      2
2010-08-01      3
2010-09-01      0
2010-10-01      5
```

And I have another pd.Series, `serie_2`, that looks like the following:

```
timestamp
2010-02-01     0
2010-03-01     0
2010-04-01     0
2010-05-01     1
2010-06-01     1
2010-07-01     2
2010-08-01     3
2010-09-01     0
2010-10-01     2
```

Note that `serie_2` starts in `2010-02-01`, while `serie_1` starts in `2010-05-01`. I need to create a pd.Series, call it `output_serie`, from both `serie_1` and `serie_2`, so that  `output_serie.index` is `serie_2.index`, and `output_serie.values` is equal to `serie_1.values/serie_2.values`.

the output would look like the following:

```
timestamp
2010-02-01     0
2010-03-01     0
2010-04-01     0
2010-05-01     2
2010-06-01     1
2010-07-01     1
2010-08-01     1
2010-09-01     0
2010-10-01     2
```

It is not a coincidence that, in both `serie_1` and `serie_2`, 0 valued timestamps are the same (for example, in `2010-09-01`).

The only problem is that `serie_2` starts in `2010-02-01`, and I need to keep those months with the 0 value in the final pd.Series.

Any help on this issue will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you display your series in a format that makes them easy to copy into a python shell?

Comment: I dont know how to do that. The key in the question is how to use an index that is greater than the index in serie_1, as i need the values computed to be a division. It won't let me do it because the size is different, so i need a solution for that. You can use any example you want, the values of serie_1 and serie_2 aren't the key of the problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [53]: serie_1.divide(serie_2).fillna(0).astype(int)
Out[53]: 
2010-02-01    0
2010-03-01    0
2010-04-01    0
2010-05-01    2
2010-06-01    1
2010-07-01    1
2010-08-01    1
2010-09-01    0
2010-10-01    2
dtype: int64
```

---

This is the setup I used:

```
import pandas as pd

serie_1 = pd.Series([2, 1, 2, 3, 0, 5], index=pd.DatetimeIndex(["2010-05-01", "2010-06-01", "2010-07-01", "2010-08-01", "2010-09-01", "2010-10-01", ]), )

serie_2 = pd.Series([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 0, 2], index=pd.DatetimeIndex(["2010-02-01", "2010-03-01", "2010-04-01", "2010-05-01", "2010-06-01", "2010-07-01", "2010-08-01", "2010-09-01", "2010-10-01", ]), )
```

Comment: It returns this error: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (6,) (9,)

Comment: Is there a difference between `.div` and `.divide`?

Comment: @Erfan: They are the same. `divide` is [an alias for `div`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/ops/methods.py#L165).